# loadURI with referrer is https - not work

Tags: firefox-addon

I created a addons firefox to fake referrer URL from a URL. But with referrer URL is 'http' then work OK, and not work for referrer URL is 'https'. Here is my code:

```js
//var rsURL = 'http://www.google.com'; //<= worked perfect
var rsURL = 'https://www.google.com'; //<= not work
var svcIO = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
var rURI = svcIO.newURI(rsURL, null, null);
gBrowser.selectedBrowser.loadURI('http://www.whatismyreferer.com/', rURI, null);
//result show: No referer / Hidden
```

So, I don't know why? You can detect my wrong code or suggest me a other way. Thanks so much !

Comment: Try using `loadOneTab`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/loadOneTab

Comment: I tried, still not work with loadOneTab. `gBrowser.loadOneTab('http://www.whatismyreferer.com/', {referrerURI: rURI})`

Comment: Thats real weird, ill try testing it later if no one posts by then.

Comment: Excuse the delay man, this seems like a tricky thing, I havent got a chance to look into it. Maybe you can get on irc and ask too:  https://client02.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23extdev

Comment: Still not resolve this isse @Noitidart